# Putting sheaves to work for algebraic topology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory

This is [cross-posted from `math.se`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043136/putting-sheaves-to-work-for-algebraic-topology) after receiving points and no answers. I apologise if this question is too basic for MathOverflow.

I'm refreshing my memory of covering space theory, and this time around, I know some sheaf theory. It feels like arguments are used to prove results about covering spaces, such as uniqueness of lifts, having something "sheafy" about them.

For example, to prove uniqueness of lifts, we argue by trying to extend "equality at a point" to "equality over a neighbourhood" to "equality over the entire domain". It seems like the language of sheaves may make this clearer?

Similarly, when it comes to covering spaces, there is something "etale-like" about them. Is there a reference that expands on this perspective?

Comment: The most general version of this I know is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07155), but there's a huge gulf of successive abstractions from covering space theory to that :).

Comment: In the PhD thesis of Ingo Blechschmidt the internal language of sheaves over a space is developed to treat the questions of when is it possible to extend 'truth at points' to 'truths over a neighbourhood' (which is global truth for sheaves, since truth glues).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For sufficiently nice topological spaces $X$ (e.g., locally connected for the last two categories to be equivalent, and semilocally simply connected and locally path-connected for all three to be equivalent), the following three categories are equivalent:

- Functors from the fundamental groupoid of $X$ to the category of sets;
- Covering spaces over $X$;
- Locally constant sheaves of sets on $X$.

This is an extremely primitive baby version of the Riemann–Hilbert correspondence.

References specifically for this elementary case are sparse,
but there is an [extensive discussion on locally constant sheaves](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/11/locally_constant_sheaves.html) at the nCafé.

Comment: Aren't the last two categories *always* equivalent (at least if you take the right definition of covering spaces as fiber bundles with discrete fibers)?

Comment: A complete discussion of the equivalence between the first two categories (in german) is in the topology textbook by Laures and Szymik.

Comment: This is a minor comment, but to my mind all three of those categories live on the same side of the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence. The other side would consist of some form of flat connections (which only really makes sense in a differential/algebro-geometric context with linear coefficients). I guess I would call the equivalence of the first two categories the Galois correspondence or something.

Comment: @DenisNardin: What other definition of a covering space do you have in mind?  From my point of view, the problem is that there are two nonequivalent definitions of a locally constant sheaf, and the one commonly given in the literature (a sheaf that is locally isomorphic to the constant sheaf) simply does not give a category equivalent to covering spaces, as explained in the linked nCafé post.

Comment: @SamGunningham: Covering spaces resemble flat connections: both admit a notion of a parallel transport that is invariant under homotopies of paths.  Both have a total space that projects to the base space.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I'm sorry but I am confused - why this notion of locally constant sheaf does not correspond to covering spaces? There's an equivalence between sheaves over $X$ and local homeomorphisms $Y→X$ given by the étalé space construction, and I thought that locally constant sheaves correspond exactly to covering spaces under this equivalence. I cannot find a discussion of this at the linked nCafé page. What am I missing?

Comment: @DenisNardin: The missing part is the proof that (after refining the cover) the transition maps can be made constant, which is required for a fiber bundle with a discrete fiber.

Comment: Hrmm... maybe I'm using a different notion of "fiber bundle". Isn't a covering space just literally a space $p:Y\to X$ such that for every point $x\in X$ there's a nbd $U$ and a homeomorphism over $U$ $f^{-1}U\cong U\times F_x$ for some discrete space $F_x$? Or are we working with a different definition? (incidentally my definition of fiber bundle is the same, except that $F$ is not required to be discrete)

Comment: @DmitiriPavlov: Sure, under some conditions all these things are equivalent. But the defining feature of the Riemann-Hilbert correspondence to my mind is the passage between the infinitesimal notion of parallel transport (i.e. a covariant derivative) and the actual positive-time parallel transport (i.e. a representation of the fundamental group). This is just a matter of terminology though. :)

Comment: For example, the term Riemann-Hilbert correspondence is used to describe the equivalence between the moduli space of flat holomorphic connections and the representations of the fundamental group of a compact Riemann surface. The latter I would freely identify with locally constant sheaves or fiber bundles with discrete fibers. But the former is of a different nature: the moduli space carries a different algebraic structure, and the equivalence is strictly transcendental in nature.

Comment: @DenisNardin: The definition I used above is that a fiber bundle with a discrete fiber F should be a morphism of stacks X→B(Aut(F)), which implies the condition I pointed above.  Of course, different definitions are possible.

Comment: @SamGunningham: But you do have (the appropriate analogue of) infinitesimal parallel transports: for a covering T→B, a map F→T with an extension of F→T→B to a germ F' of F admits a unique extension to a map F'→T.  Germs take over finite-order or formal neighborhoods in this setting, so this is the appropriate analogue of infinitesimal parallel transport.

Comment: @DenisNardin: A potential point of confusion may have arisen when you referred to the "right definition of covering spaces as fiber bundles with discrete fibers".  I assumed you meant to use a nonequivalent (i.e., "right") definition, but perhaps it is best to clarify what exactly you mean here.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I said "right" because some people ask the decomposition $p^{-1}U=\coprod_\alpha U_\alpha$ to be the path-connected component decomposition (which breaks the whole theory utterly in the case of not locally path-connected spaces). It is clear that the issue is another one here (I still think the definition I gave in my comment above is the "standard" one though, "right" is ofc a matter of preference).

Comment: @DmitiriPavlov Yes I agree with what you are saying (for a suitable notion of germ). My comment is really just about what aspect of this situation the term "Riemann-Hilbert correspondence" refers to. Perhaps the terminology is a culture dependent to some extent.

Comment: @DmitiriPavlov I guess there are really 2 independent flavours of correspondence: firstly, between fibrations and representations (parallel transport construction) and secondly between infinitesimal and "honest" parallel transport (integration). The infinitesimal/honest distinction can be quite large in algebraic and analytic geometry. e.g. D-modules have infinitesimal parallel transport by definition, but only very special ones (holonomic) admit parallel transport along "honest" paths. I realize that you are coming more from homotopy theory though, so these comments are kind of off-topic